# Google map contained in meteor Template is rendered twice

Tags: google-maps-api-3, meteor

I have the following template:

```
<template name="test">
  {{#isolate}}
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:50%; height:50%"></div>
  {{/isolate}}
</template>
```

In my test.js (from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld) :

```
function initialize(){
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map_canvas")[0], mapOptions);
}

Template.test.rendered = function(){
    initialize();
  //*** The following is the workaround I am using:***
  // if (! this.initialized){
  //   initialize();
  //   this.initialized = true;
  // }
};
```

The problem is: without the workaround shown in the commented code section, the template is always rendered twice (as initialize() is run). It's both shown in console logs (logging code not shown here) and also visible from the map flashing once (which is not acceptable).

The reason, I am guessing, is from the following events happending:

1. the template is rendered, with `$('#map_canvas')` generated as a simple div element (no map attached);
2. google map api returns aync-ly and modifies `$('#map_canvas')`;
3. somehow Meteor detects the change, and in spite of `{{#isolate}}`, decides to render the whole template once again (this is shown in log);
4. initialize() is called again, within `Template.test.rendered`.

My questions:

1. why?
2. if this is what happened, why is Meteor only rendering twice, instead of infinite times?
3. solution?

3 questions and lots of thanks!

Comment: Hello, how did you manage to include your google maps api external file in the correct order? I put it in <head> but when I call for it it complains its not there..

Answer (score 4):

The template is probably being rendered twice due to the outer context that contains `{{> test}}` being re-rendered. There's a variety of reasons why this might happen, but usually it's just that it renders initially without subscription data, and then a second time when the data has loaded.

Anyway, in your specific case, I think what you want is a `{{#constant}}` wrapper around your google map, rather than an `{{#isolate}}`.

**NOTE**: `{{#constant}}` areas *do* get re-rendered if (for whatever reason) the surrounding context is re-rendered. However the new version gets thrown away rather than replaced in the DOM. So just be careful in you `rendered` callback to only do something *the first time*.

Comment: "Comments are only editable in 5 minutes" - Sorry.
Thank you for the answer. I finally got a chance to test this out. {{#contant}} did not work either. The outer template containing `test`: (I tested with a simple outer template):
     

     <template name="index">
          {{> test}}
     </template>

So I doubt that the outer template is causing this.

Comment: Note that `{{#constant}}` templates do get re-rendered (ie. `rendered` is called, along with helpers). However they do not get _replaced_ so whatever was put there the first time will remain. You just need to be a little careful in the callback. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Got your answer update. Thanks. So I something like the commented block in `rendered` has to be put there. I was actually looking for something like `first_rendered` to avoid this boilerplate. I tried with `created` but it's a call back before that.

Comment: Yes, I think you need something like that.